# Resource (CPU time and memory) limitation and termination of a process upon violation in Linux

Tags: process, memory, monitoring, cpu, cpu-usage

**The problem:**

Given a process, limit the resources it and its child-processes can use. I.e. set CPU time and virtual memory quotas. When the process group exceeds one of the limits, terminate it, otherwise print the amount of CPU time and virtual memory it has used.

**The concrete use case:**

Basically I must execute a couple of binaries, which expect input from a file, but I must ensure that their execution process is strictly limited. For example the binary must not allocate more than 256 MB of memory and it should run for less than 0.5 seconds. However I need information about the amount of memory and CPU it has used.

**What I have tried:**

1. For a couple of days I have been dealing with [this perl script](https://github.com/pshved/timeout), which is the best solution I have found so far. Unfortunately its memory is buggy and it is not very precise. Also there is an official author post about this script [here](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40).
2. I have tried using both `/usr/bin/timeout`  and `timeout` Linux tools, which of course help me with the CPU time quota, but not with the termination of the process due to violation of the virtual memory limit.
3. Using `ulimit` was attempted as well but as I have said earlier I need not only limitation but feedback for the resource consumption too.

**The Question:**

What can solve this issue? .

Comment: Your question is too broad IMHO. Could you motivate it more and give more details. So please **edit your question** to improve it. What is the software you have trouble with? Do you have its source code?

Comment: Basically I must execute a couple of binaries, which expect input from a file, but I must ensure that their execution process is strictly limited. For example the binary must not allocate more than 256 MB of memory and it should run for less than 0.5 seconds. Hope this makes sense now. However I need information about the amount of memory and CPU it used.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting it. BTW, my answer fits (except that `setrlimit` can limit CPU time only for an integral number of seconds)

Comment: Can you raise the 0.5 CPU second limit to 1 second? If yes, use `setrlimit`

Comment: Are you able to code in C or any programming language giving access to Linux low level syscalls?

Comment: Actually the CPU and memory limits are variables. I.e. they are not fixed - can be any numbers. I am currently reading your suggestions. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Yes, I can code in C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25859/discussion-between-0x450-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Comment: I will do this for sure, as soon as I have enough reputation here to do so.

Comment: You should have said that it is for some software for a competition about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall is relevant to limit resources (CPU time -integral number of seconds, so at least 1 sec- with `RLIMIT_CPU`, file size with `RLIMIT_FSIZE`, address space with `RLIMIT_AS`, etc...). You could also set up [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota). The [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) syscall tells you -and gives feedback- about some resource usage. And [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) tells you a lot more, and also [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) (you might code some monitor which periodically stops the entire process group using `SIGSTOP`, call `getrusage` or query `/proc/$PID/`, then send `SIGCONT` -to continue- or `SIGTERM` -to terminate- to that process group).

The [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) tool is very useful on Linux to help finding memory leaks. And [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) should be helpful too.

If you can recompile the faulty software, you could consider `-fsanitize=address` and `-fsanitize=undefined` and other `-fsanitize=`... options to a recent version of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler.

Perhaps you have some [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing).  Look for batch monitors, or simply code your own thing in C, Python, Ocaml, Perl, .... (which forks the command, and loop on monitoring it...). Maybe you want some process accounting (see [acct(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acct.5.html) & [sa(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sa.8.html)...)

Notice that "amount of memory used" (a program generally allocates with `mmap` & releases memory with `munmap` to the kernel while running) and "CPU time" (see [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), think of multi-threaded programs ...) are very fuzzy concepts.

See also [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) and configure things under `/etc/security/` ; perhaps [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) might also be helpful (but probably not).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)